# Upload via HTTPS PUT without back-end script handler

Tags: https, upload, put, centos7, apache2.4

Is there a way to upload a file to https server via PUT method without a server side script to handle the request? I configured the server, but if I try this request, I get 405 error (The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to enable something like WebDav if you don't provide your own way to process a PUT.  The core of the server don't write out files.

Comment: Exactly! Works fine! I enable mod_dav_fs and mod_dav on apache.
https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-webdav-with-apache2-on-centos-5.5